# Finalizing the Joomla Installation in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, beginner

I am new to Joomla, I have installed it on Ubuntu 21.04 / with apache2 & Mariadb-server/client.
My issue at the moment when attempting to access the Joomla via a web browser and Error appears (see below images)

Additionally, I have enabled both the **configuration.php-dist** & **php.ini** files to display error reporting, however, no errors are being displayed. I have a sense the error might be related to the joomla.conf, then again ‍♂️

[image]

Here is the joomla.conf:

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should be using whatever you've defined fo `ServerName` in your browser. But try replacing `.com` with something like `.local`.

Comment: Virtualhost will not have an effect, because you are not using a domain name in the browser but 127.0.0.1. You have to make a copy of configuration.php-dist and name it configuration.php for Joomla to read it.  Does www-data have write access to the /var/www/html/joomla directory?

Comment: Thanks @Lodder for the suggestion!

Comment: configuration.php is also created by Joomla during installation.

Comment: @Geoffrey - yes indeed permissions has been set as the following:

drwxr-xr-x 18 www-data www-data

About the configuration.php-dist, I've now changed it as configuration.php, however, via the same browser url:  http://127.0.1.1/joomla/installation/index.php

   error reporting displays the below

Error: Call to undefined function Joomla\CMS\Language\simplexml_load_file(): Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file()

Comment: Is the php-xml extension enabled?

Comment: The `configuration.php` is not required for the installation process

Comment: Have you installed all the necessary php server modules for your PHP version? See https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements

Comment: I think Geoffrey may be right, try installing the php-xml extension using something like `sudo apt-get install php-xml` or `sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml` (change 7.4 to whatever version of PHP you are using). Then either reboot the server or reload PHP using `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

Comment: Just extending on what Pe7er said, check your php.ini file hasn't disabled the PHP functions that Joomla needs. In the past, I've found that I needed chmod, php_uname, and curl_exec (and depending on software installed getmypid) to not be listed in the disable_functions section of the php.ini. I can't remember if that was for J3 or J4 though.

Comment: After changing php.ini, you will need to reload PHP. Either reboot the server or type `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart` <- Again 7.4 in this case is the version of PHP installed on my server. The php.ini file is probably located somewhere around `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini` <- Again 7.4 is the version of php running on one of my servers, so you may need to change it. You can generally find error logs at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (or `/var/log/nginx/error.log` if you were using nginx).

Answer (score 1):

If 'configuration.php-dist' exists you have not installed Joomla.

Check here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Joomla

For a Guide to Installing Joomla! on an Ubuntu Server.

Change your apache2/sites-available/joomla.conf to {modify to your situation}:

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1 xxx.xx.xx.xx>
DocumentRoot "/www/server1"
ServerName server.example.com
ServerAlias server

If you continue to have issues, post them here.

Comment: Change YourSite.conf to something similar to: